# How to Properly Declare MIME Type for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

My website that uses HTML and client-side javascript gives me a MIME type error that I need help solving.

I try importing my javascript files with lines like `<script src="./src/javascript/loadheaderfooter.js"></script>` but in Firefox, I get the the error messages in the image below.

My javascript files just contain a few function definitions and no other text.

I am using a python simple http server to localhost the site.

Please let me know how I can solve the error. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Python's simple http is just too simple.

Comment: You need to configure your HTTP server to report the correct MIME type when serving .js files.